# Why is subclass field initialized to its default value within super constructor?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I am trying to understand the output of the java toy program below...

```
public class BaseWithPrint {

    public BaseWithPrint(){
        print();
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("BaseWithPrint.print");

    }
}

class DerivedWithPrint extends BaseWithPrint{
    int i = 47;
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
    }
}

class Initialization_MYCLASS{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        DerivedWithPrint dp = new DerivedWithPrint();
        dp.print();
    }
}
```

The output of this file is:

```
i = 0
i = 47
```

I understand why I get the second line. But is the first line `i = 0`?